# Best way to chain nested loops of mutations in React-Query?

Tags: javascript, react-query

Let's say I have the following piece of data, a list of `puzzle` objects, where each object has a `puzzle_name` field and a list of `patterns` within it:

```
const puzzles = [
    {
      puzzle_name: 'Test Data 1',
      patterns: [
        {pattern_name: 'test', type: 'test type', hours: 12},
        {pattern_name: 'test 2', type: 'test type 2', hours: 22}
      ]
    },
    {
      puzzle_name: 'Test Data 2',
      patterns: [
        {pattern_name: 'test', type: 'test type', hours: 12},
        {pattern_name: 'test 2', type: 'test type 2', hours: 22},
        {pattern_name: 'test 3', type: 'test type 3', hours: 33}
      ]
    }
  ];
```

The goal here is to create each of the puzzles first (using *just* their names), get their ID once created, and create each individual pattern using the puzzle's ID. So I need to talk to two POST routes for this list of data. The first one takes a single object with the `pattern_name` field, so -

`POST /puzzle` takes `{puzzle_name: string}` as the body and returns `{puzzle_name: string, puzzle_id: string}`

The second route needs this `puzzle_id` in its param and a single `pattern` object at a time (from the `patterns` list above) -

So that would be `POST /my-app.com/{puzzleId}/pattern`, which takes a `pattern` object as its body and it returns the newly created object, which we don't need to worry about for the sake of this example.

Now for my attempt at this, I have the following two mutations -

```
  const createPuzzleMutation = useMutation(({body}) => createPuzzle(body));
  
  const createPatternMutation = useMutation(({puzzleId, body}) => createPattern(puzzleId, body));
```

And then I'm iterating through `puzzles` and creating a list of promises for the `createPuzzleMutation`. In the `onSuccess` function for each `puzzle`, I'm then going through the corresponding `patterns` list and calling the `createPatternMutation` using the ID of the puzzle, like so -

```
const puzzlesMutations = puzzles.map((puzzle) =>
  createPuzzleMutation.mutateAsync(
    {body: {name: puzzle.puzzle_name}},
    {
      onSuccess: async (data) => {
        const patternsMutations = puzzle.patterns.map((pattern) => {
          return createPatternMutation.mutateAsync(
            {
              puzzle_id: data.data.id,
              body: {
                ...pattern
              }
            }
          );
        });
        // waiting for all patterns to be created under a particular puzzle
        await Promise.allSettled(patternsMutations);
      }
    }
  )
);
// waiting for an individual puzzle to be created
await Promise.allSettled(puzzlesMutations);
```

It's creating both the puzzle names just fine, so it's talking to the first route, the `POST /puzzle` route just fine and getting the ID's for both the puzzles. But it's only calling the second route (`POST /my-app.com/{puzzleId}/pattern`) for the `patterns` list in the *second* puzzle. It's not calling the second POST route for the `patterns` array in the first puzzle.

I saw in the [docs](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/mutations#consecutive-mutations) that for consecutive mutations, they'll be fired only once. Is this constraint related to my example here? Or am I missing something? Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

> I saw in the docs that for consecutive mutations, they'll be fired only once. Is this constraint related to my example here?

yes it is. If you want a callback that fires for every invocation of a mutation, you need to use the `onSuccess` callback of `useMutation` itself, *not* the callback on `mutateAsync`. There, you can also *return* a Promise, and react-query will `await` it before marking the mutation as "finished".

```
const createPuzzleMutation = useMutation(
  ({body}) => createPuzzle(body),
  {
     onSuccess: async (data) => {
        const patternsMutations = puzzle.patterns.map((pattern) => {
          return createPatternMutation.mutateAsync(
            {
              puzzle_id: data.data.id,
              body: {
                ...pattern
              }
            }
          );
        });
        // waiting for all patterns to be created under a particular puzzle
        return Promise.allSettled(patternsMutations);
      }
  }
  }
);
```